# How to style icons inside Button component which assigned with leftIcon/rightIcon props [Chakra-UI]?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm trying to style `<Button/>` components via `extendTheme()`. Core styles are doing fine, any colour, size, spacing changes are working perfectly. But I'm having trouble to style `<Button/>` component with any `leftIcon`/`rightIcon` property. Overall I need to update icon part of button, which `margin-inline-start`/`margin-inline-end` properties of Icons but it is not same as other multi-part components in Chakra-UI while we can see the `"chakra-button__icon"` class on elements.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's not possible. Have a look at the `Button` [source code](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/5d583e6636029f7777a9db630799a741ff637edd/packages/components/button/src/button.tsx#L138) which directly renders `leftIcon` and `rightIcon`respectively inside a `ButtonIcon` which get passed `margin` styles. Apparantly this has been discussed before in [this issue](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/2989).

Ultimately, you could build your own `ButtonWithIcon` component that's more customizable

Answer (score 0):

You can add that in `sx` props like below.

```
<Button `sx={{ '.chakra-button__icon *': { color: 'red' } }}` `rightIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}`>Sign up`</Button>`
```